# Взаимодействие с другой функцией

Tags: php, ооп, функции

Есть функция `bord("text")`, как сделать взаимодействие с функцией `bold()`? Пример: `bord("text")->bold("text2");`, чтобы при выводе было "text text2"

Answer (score 0):

Ну например как вариант так:

```php
<?php

class Foo {
    public function bord($str)
    {
        echo $str;
        return $this;
    }

    public function bold($str)
    {
        echo ' ' . $str;
        return $this;
    }
}

$f = new Foo();
$f->bord('text')->bold('text2');
```

А в целом все зависит от фантазии и требований. Можете описать подробнее, что хотите сделать ?